# Cant install pip keyboard module

Tags: python

I have tried several times to install the keyboard module!
I am using Python 2.7.16 on a Mac! It says it was installed successfully! But as soon as I use it in a script, comes the following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/aaronhessler/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Users/aaronhessler/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator*
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks for your Help (:

Comment: You need to run the python that you instated the library for

Comment: Show how hi installed it. I don't see any reason you did it for your python 2.7 install

Comment: Periods are fine. You don't need an exclamation mark for everything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to a ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.